# Считать double из файла С++

Tags: c++

Необходимо считать значения типа double из файла и записать их в вектор. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать? С++

Comment: считать значения типа double из файла и записать их в вектор

Comment: Файлы бывают разные. Считать текстовое представление значений `double` из файла - это одно. Считать бинарное представление значений `double` из файла - это совсем другое. А вам что нужно?

Comment: Как Вы пытались это сделать? (кроме вариантов: "гуглил готовое решение" или "надеялся что на стековерфлов кто-то напишер решение нашару").

Comment: Из текстового файла. Прошу прощения, что не уточнил сразу - минусовать было не обязательно, наверное. Я редко использую готовые решения и стараюсь разобраться в том, что мне дают. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если файл текстовый, то можно так:

```
ifstream file("doubleVals.txt");
// Здесь проверка на открытие файла
vector<double> values;
copy(istream_iterator<double>(file), istream_iterator<double>(), back_inserter(values));
file.close();
```

Если файл бинарный, то можно так:

```
ifstream file("doubleVals.dat", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
// Здесь проверка на открытие файла
vector<double> values;
double temp;
while (file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&temp), sizeof(double)))
{
    values.push_back(temp);
}
file.close();
```